# Use methods and variables of an Activity from another Activity in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, global-variables

I'm trying to execute some methods defined in the `MainActivity` but in another activity called `SecondActivity`. Those methods also modify variables defined in the `MainActivity`.

I know that when one `Activity` covers another, you have no guarantee how long the first Activity will stay alive and in many cases it will be destroyed very quickly so you can't rely on being able to call a method in one `Activity` from another. It's also not the way that Android is supposed to work. But I'm trying to get in the `SecondActivity` the `MainActivity` instance that I'm using when I'm on the `MainActivity`, is it possible?

I've already tried making `MainActivity` `Serializable` and passing it in the method `Intent.putSerializableExtra` but it didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for but you could always extend the main class to the second one to use super.methods from the parent. `SecondActivity extends MainActivity`

Comment: Hi Julia. I'm looking for a way to use the same Instance that I've previously created at the beggining of the app. I mean: When I'm on the MainActivity I'm using an instance of the MainActivity, and I want to keep it with me when I go to the SecondActivity. Is it possible?

Comment: Check out this [page](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html). Here's a useful blurb `To save additional data about the activity state, you must override the onSaveInstanceState() callback method. The system calls this method when the user is leaving your activity and passes it the Bundle object that will be saved in the event that your activity is destroyed unexpectedly. ** If the system must recreate the activity instance later, it passes the same Bundle object to both the onRestoreInstanceState() and onCreate() methods. **`

Comment: Yeah, it's useful but to pass the instance using this method I should make my class serializable and it's attributes, and I'm not able to do it...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood you quite well, but I recommend creating a class that contains static methods, which makes them accessible anywhere.

```
class HelperMethods {
  static void method1(args){
   //do something using arguments
  }
}

class MainActivity {
   HelperMethods.method1(new Object);
}
class SecondActivity {
  HelperMethods.method1(new Object2);
}
```

As for changing variables in main activity, you set those variables as static, and modify them from the method inside HelperMethods class.

Comment: Hi. I need the MainActivity instance that I've previously created when the MainActivity was started, that's useless to me because I need that instance in the SecondActivity to create an object that depends on it.